# behaviour of dimension.top in case of array dimensions in crossfilter

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

What exactly is the behaviour of dimension.top in case of array dimensions?

It seems to be sorting on the first value in the array across all rows.

Shouldn't it be sorting on all values putting at top the record that includes the highest value anywhere in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should return an array with the same number of elements as there are array elements in all rows. Each row will appear once for each element in its array, ordered by the value of that element. If you are seeing different behavior, please post an example and I or someone else will be happy to take a look.

Comment: So the highest value in the array will be in the first ordered row, but that value within the row will remain in its position ? So values are not ordered within a row? [70, 68, 63, 62, 59, 110] is the top one, but value '110' is the last element in the array

Comment: Correct. The record returned is just the unaltered data, so the array should be in whatever order you have it in in your data.

Comment: I was using dim.top and dim.bottom to get the boundaries for a dynamically generated dc-plot so in this case I have to do array.max and array.min after calling dim.top and dim.bottom. As a suggestion shouldn't top/bottom return the values also sorted within the array. This way dim.top[0][val][0] will always have the highest or lowest value

Comment: You can open an issue to discuss. There are some big problems with doing this as it interferes with other use cases, but we can certainly talk about it.